# Merging several df according to one column organized by another column

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I am trying to achieve the following: I have several dataframes over several years.

```
df1
Name   Ch1   Val1   Val2   ..
A       a     x1     x2
B       a     x3     x4
...
```

```
df2
Name   Ch1   Val1   Val2   ..
A       b     x5     x6
B       b     x7     x8
...
```

```
df3
Name   Ch1   Val1   Val2   ..
A       c     x9     x10
C       c     x11    x12
...
```

While a,b,c are years so lets say 2002, 2003, 2004.

Now I want to merge these dataframes so that each value of `Name` is listed for all years (i.e. `Ch1`) like the following:

```
df_final
Name   Ch1   Val1   Val2   ..
A       a     x1     x2
        b     x5     x6
        c     x9     x10
B       a     x3     x4
        b     x6     x7
C       c     x11    x12
...
```

The problem is also that the values for "Name" are not always the same for all 3 dataframes (e.g. C).

Answer (score 3):

*Using `dplyr`:*

```r
library(dplyr)

bind_rows(df1,df2,df3) %>% 
  arrange(Name, Ch1) %>% 
  mutate(Name = replace(Name, duplicated(Name), ""))

#>   Name Ch1 Val1 Val2
#> 1    A   a   x1   x2
#> 2        b   x5   x6
#> 3        c   x9  x10
#> 4    B   a   x3   x4
#> 5        b   x7   x8
#> 6    C   c  x11  x12
```

***Data:***

```
df1 <- read.table(text="
Name   Ch1   Val1   Val2  
A       a     x1     x2
B       a     x3     x4", header=T, stringsAsFactor=F)

df2 <- read.table(text="
Name   Ch1   Val1   Val2
A       b     x5     x6
B       b     x7     x8", header=T, stringsAsFactor=F)

df3 <- read.table(text="
Name   Ch1   Val1   Val2
A       c     x9     x10
C       c     x11    x12", header=T, stringsAsFactor=F)
```